# C# StreamWriter Buffer Size Does Not Work

Tags: c#, buffer, streamwriter

I would like to set a small buffer so the buffer can be written to file more frequently. But it seems this does not work. I wrote the following code and check the text file from time to time and find that text is written to file when i = 840 and the file size is exactly 4K, which is the default buffer size. How come?

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("u:\\log.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8, 1))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(i);
                Console.Write(i);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The default buffer size of the underlying FileStream is 4096. Also StreamWriter has a minimum buffer size of 128.

Comment: You are creating the buffer of 1 byte and what is the size of integer variable that you are writing in file? just take a look at it.

Comment: I will also note that, contra the documentation, the buffer size is number of 16-bit characters not bytes. See the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs).

Comment: I tried to set buffer size to be 128, 2048, 4096 and 8192. It seems only 4096 and 8192 works, that is the buffer flushed when the file size were 4096 and 8192 respectively. So I think the minimum is 4096.

Comment: And buffer size should be the number of bytes, see the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf7ab94(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @mikez Many thanks. But I am still confused by the source code and my test result. Could you please repeat the experiment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StreamWriter uses an underlying FileStream, and based on the source code, it looks like the buffer size isn't passed to the file stream.

You can google: .net source code streamwriter

Comment: I read the source code. In fact the buffer size is passed to the file stream. But there is a minimum buffer, which is 4096.